# Letting administrative level users other than 'administrator' access c$ in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

It seems only 'administrator' can open `c$` in Windows 7. Is there no way to let administrator group members other than administrator access these shares?

When I try to edit the share permissions, it gives me some system built-in share with settings that cannot be edited.

Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a user to the local Administrators group via Computer Management:

[image]

---

You're right, it seems they've disabled local administrators from using their permissions for network shares since Vista, you can edit the registry to change this:

1. Click start
2. Type: regedit
3. Press enter
4. In the left, browse to the following folder:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\
   ```
5. Right-click a blank area in the right pane
6. Click New
7. Click DWORD Value
8. Type: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
9. Double-click the item you just created
10. Type 1 into the box
11. Click OK
12. Restart your computer

Comment: That works on XP, not on Vista/7 though --

Comment: it does with a registry tweak ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the steps from the first answer (above)...but something else has to be done.  You must also turn off UAC, or the above does nothing for you.